# Reach Docker container from other docker Container within localhost:port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Current compose yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  php:
    container_name: docker_php
    build: .docker/php73
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/
    networks:
      - app-tier

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: docker_rabbitmq
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbitmq-localhost"
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    networks:
      - app-tier
```

My target is to reach docker_rabbitmq container from docker_php within localhost:

```
#bash php_container
telnet loaclhost 15672
```

How can I  configure a network that:

container A has  port mapping on localhost to Container B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're limited by the inner port, which means if your two containers are in the same docker defined network, you can use the internally opened ports of the respective container. For the `hostname` to be defined for a container in a different one, you can use the `links` attribute in the service definition inside your `docker-compose.yml`.

Consider a micro service which you want to be only accessed by only the containers on that network therefore exposing the ports on the host wouldn't make sense. Now assuming `rabbitmq` is the service that you want to access from `php` service, you need to define a link to `rabbitmq` in your `php` service definition( please not the link/host-definition is not bi-directional, if you need `php` in your `rabbitmq` you need to define a link in `rabbitmq` for `php`)

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  php:
    container_name: docker_php
    build: .docker/php73
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/
    networks:
      - app-tier
    links:
      - rabbitmq

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: docker_rabbitmq
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbitmq-localhost"
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    networks:
      - app-tier
```

Now you can access the internal ports of the `rabbitmq` from `php` but note the expternal ports are not accessible, those are for the host.

```
# inside your `php` container `bash`
telnet rabbitmq <internal_port>
```

Also not that I got rid of the ports in `rabbitmq` by removing

now these ports of `rabbitmq` are not accessible from the host.

## Update

if you want to access the ports, such that the ports opened in `rabbitmq` are accessible in `php` on localhost. the easiest and the simplest way would be to configure `rabbitmq` to run in container network mode on the network of `php` to do this simple add
network_mode: "container:[container name/id]"

```
rabbitmq:
    container_name: docker_rabbitmq
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbitmq-localhost"
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    network_mode: "container:php"
    ports:
        - "15672:15672"
        - "5672:5672"
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve it, that php container could reach rabbitmq container not by ```rabbitmq``` host , but from ```localhost```?

like:

```
 inside your `php` container `bash`
telnet localhost <internal_port of rabbitmq>
```

Comment: @Mindau its possible using 2 ways, `socat` and using the host network.

Comment: thanks for the answer. network mode did exactly what i needed. I just used 
```
network_mode: "service:php"
```

Comment: You can make connections between containers using their container name without doing any of the manual setup you suggest here: you do not need `links:` or a custom `network:` or `network_mode:` setup.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this reasonably well.